# Time-delayed grequests without using grequests.map()

Tags: python, python-requests, grequests

This is the first time I've tried to use a library with less-than-ideal levels of documentation and example code, so bear with me. I have a tiny bit of experience with the Requests library, but I need to send separate requests to a specific address every second:

- Without waiting for the first request to complete,  handling the
  individual responses as they come in
- The responses' content need to be parsed separately
- While limiting the total number of connections

I can't figure out how to satisfy these conditions simultaneously. `grequests.map()` will give me the responses' content that I want, but only in a batch after they've all completed. `grequests.send()` seems to only return a response object that doesn't contain the html text of the web page. (I may be wrong about `grequests.send()`, but I haven't yet found an example that pulls content from that object)

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
import grequests
from time import sleep

def print_res(res, **kwargs):
    print res
    print kwargs

headers =   {'User-Agent':'Python'}

req = grequests.get('http://stackoverflow.com', headers=headers, hooks=dict(response=print_res), verify=False)

for i in range(3):
    job = grequests.send(req, grequests.Pool(10))
    sleep(1)
```

The response I get:

```
1
<Response [200]>
{'verify': False, 'cert': None, 'proxies': {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888', 'ht
tps': 'https://127.0.0.1:8888'}, 'stream': False, 'timeout': None}
2
<Response [200]>
{'verify': False, 'cert': None, 'proxies': {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888', 'ht
tps': 'https://127.0.0.1:8888'}, 'stream': False, 'timeout': None}
3
<Response [200]>
{'verify': False, 'cert': None, 'proxies': {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888', 'ht
tps': 'https://127.0.0.1:8888'}, 'stream': False, 'timeout': None}
```

I've tried accessing the html response with `req.content`, and `job.content`, but neither work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course, while writing up this question I realized that I hadn't tried to access `res.content`, which turns out to be exactly what I needed.

Lesson learned: The object that is returned to the response hook in the `grequests.get()` statement has a `content` attribute which contains the text of the response sent from the server.